# How to keep app's backstack when using implicit deeplink? (Nav component)

Tags: android, kotlin

Imagine i have a link. In my app i have bottom navigation and deep link to 3rd fragment in menu. When I press on link i'm heading to 3rd fragment as expected. But if i will try to press any another fragment from bottom menu my app is crash because this fragments not in backstack. Is there any method how can i make my app act normal after open fragment through deeplink?

Comment: did you manage to solve it? Mine have a similar problem, only the start fragment is not in the backstack.